# problems with simpleauth install mac

Tags: google-app-engine, installation

can't get simpleauth to install, keeps giving me 'No module named' errors, I install what it says is missing up to 'google.appengine.api' which I know is install according to the sdk instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. download simpleauth to the /usr/local/google_appengine directory
2. edit setup.py

   - Add to top

   import sys
   sys.path.append('/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/')
3. run setup:

   - from cmd line:

   python setup.py build
   sudo python setup.py install